# CiviMobile local timezone

Tags: timezone, civimobile

When I create activities etc. on CiviMobile in my Time Zone I am in it displays as 9 hours later.  Currently I am -7 GMT and when setting an activity on the app it automatically changes it to +2 GMT (9 hours ahead of my time zone). When I look on CiviCRM, the activities I created in CiviMobile are 9 hours ahead there too. I’m using the latest CiviMobile on and iPhone. How do I get CiviMobile to use the time/time zone on my phone?

Answer (score 2):

Jerry, Welcome to CiviCRM stackexchange, your civicrm database stores certain fields with data-type "DATETIME". To improve timezone support, you may want to change these from "DATETIME" to "TIMESTAMP".

For further discussion, please visit https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.doctorwhen

Answer (score 1):

This is a workaround, not a solution:
Comment out the `time_zone_utc_offset` in **PublicSettings.php**, in **Cms.php** and in **CiviMobileSystem.php**

CiviMobile takes the server timezone-settings. Depending on what has been configured there, the result can be misleading...